# Retornar uma das funções em jquery.

Tags: jquery

Olá é possivel retornar separadamente uma desta duas funções que estão dentro de outra função ?
Por exemplo dependendo da situação quero retornar o resultado da function pergunta e em outro momento a function resposta ?

```js
function psNF(){
    var pergunta = function(){
        alert('a');
    }
    var resposta = function(){
        alert('b');
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer retornar a função ou só executar ela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode chamar a função passando um determinado parâmetro, dessa forma não existe a necessidade de criar mais de uma função para chamar as funções.

```
function psNF(opcao) {

  if (opcao == 1) {
    var pergunta = function() {
      alert('a');
    }
  } else {
    var resposta = function() {
      alert('b');
    }
  }
}
```

Lembre-se que o parâmetro quem define é você. Você pode passar `int,string,char` e ***diversos outros tipos***. Só precisa ficar ligado na hora da condição `if` para fazer o tratamento correto.

E é claro no momento de chamar a função, passar o parâmetro que você deseja.

Comment: Obrigado, isso abriu muitas opções para o que pretendo fazer!

Comment: Que bom Carlos! O céu é o limite.

Answer (score 0):

Só criar uma função nomeada separada pra cada uma delas

```
function psNF(){
    var pergunta = function(){
        alert('a');
    }
}

function rpNF(){
    var resposta = function(){
        alert('b');
    }
}
```

Aí atribui o chamado da função aonde você for usar cada uma.

```
<button type="button" name="pergunta" onclick="psNF();" />

<button type="button" name="resposta" onclick="rpNF();" />
```